# pass object into ajax search

Tags: jquery, ajax

is it possible to pass a search term into the ajax search, instead of hardcoding the query? I've been messing around with object literals or some form of associative array but none have worked. 
Below is what I'm going for with "Search object" being the object to pass into the query:

```
acTest = $.ajax(**searchObject**{
        url: "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
             key: UserConfig.bingMapsKey,
             q:**SearchObject**
            },
            jsonp: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                var result = data.resourceSets[0];
                if (result) {
                        if (result.estimatedTotal > 0) {
                                response ($.map(result.resources, function (item) {
                                        return {
                                            data: item,
                                            label: item.name + '(' item.address.countryRegion + ')',
                                            value: item.name
                                        }
                                }));
                        }
                }
            }
});
```

Comment: can you give an example for the search term?

Comment: This is why WebSockets+nodejs make my life so much easier.

Comment: What is with the two placements of `**searchObject**`? The first one makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, simply pass in a variable

```
var searchQuery = $('#queryTextBoxId').val();

acTest = $.ajax({
        url: "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
             key: UserConfig.bingMapsKey,
             q: searchQuery
            },
            jsonp: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                var result = data.resourceSets[0];
                if (result) {
                        if (result.estimatedTotal > 0) {
                                response ($.map(result.resources, function (item) {
                                        return {
                                            data: item,
                                            label: item.name + '(' item.address.countryRegion + ')',
                                            value: item.name
                                        }
                                }));
                        }
                }
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your searchObject is an actual object, you should be able to pass in the value of `JSON.stringify(searchObject)`